# What's a good test to compare performance of different Ajax frameworks?

Tags: php, ajax, frameworks, performance

I want to compare the performance of different PHP/Ajax frameworks.  I'm not looking for tools to run the tests, I'm looking for what tests to run.  I'm in the design phase of a project so I don't have an existing app.

I'd like to build the same page in several different frameworks and compare things like the generated client-side code and amount of data included in the Ajax requests.  I'm wondering what functionality to build in my sample page that will give a good comparison.

Hope this makes sense, feel free to edit if it could be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to benchmark something is to use it in a real world scenario, then wrap this code around it

```
// header
list ($_time_start_msec, $_time_start_sec) = split (" ", microtime());
$_time_start = $_time_start_sec + $_time_start_msec;

//<!-- APP HERE -->

// footer
list ($_time_finish_msec, $_time_finish_sec) = split (" ", microtime());
$_total_secs = ($_time_finish_sec + $_time_finish_msec) - $_time_start;
print '<p><small>This entire page took '. round($_total_secs, 5) .' seconds to render, which gives us '. round((1 / $_total_secs), 1) .' <span title="Pages Per Second">PPS</span> or '. number_format((1 / $_total_secs * 60), ".", 0, ",") .' <span title="Pages Per Minute">PPM</span>.</small></p>';
```

Comment: Ok, that helps, but what I'm looking for are some real-world scenarios to test.